# c++ Boost Multithread Running Slow when two threads read file and tokenize the CSV File

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

I have two functions, it used to work for me, I did some changes in the codes but I don't know what happened. When I executed those functions as multi-threads, the CPU is 10-30%, and it is so slow. It just readfile by line then parse the CSV line using boost token.

```
        boost::thread OffLineUL(&AvaTTi::AvaCollectTTiAdvance::UeAndCellParamParseUL,c,tracefilenameUL.c_str(),NumOfLines,GHOSTFILTER,"","/",OffLineMode,OPENEXCELAUTO);
        boost::thread OffLineDL(&AvaTTi::AvaCollectTTiAdvance::UeAndCellParamParseDL,c,tracefilenameDL.c_str(), NumOfLines,"","/",OffLineMode,OPENEXCELAUTO);
        OffLineDL.join();
        OffLineUL.join();


    int AvaCollectTTiAdvance::UeAndCellParamParseDL(const char *inname, int NumOfRecords, const char *UserDir, const char* CurrentDir, int OffLineMode, int OPENEXCELAUTO)
    {
       typedef boost::tokenizer <boost::escaped_list_separator<char> > my_tokenizer;
       vector <string> mystr;


      std::ifstream infile(TTiAsciiTraceOutputUserDir.str(),std::ios::in);
      while (getline(infile, line)  && lineCount <= NumOfRecords)

      for (my_tokenizer::iterator it(tok.begin()), end(tok.end()); it != end; ++it)
      { 
        mystr.push_back(*it);
      }
      ....................
      ....................
```

Can anyone please help? I am running out ideas. Thanks.

Comment: is that a shared vector: mystr?

Comment: You are parsing the same file: tracefilenameUL  ???

Comment: if I use mutex.lock before while loop and mutex.unlock() after file finish, then it gets faster but not really multi-threaded.

Comment: I am using VS 2010, do I need to do anything with project settings? I think I did some changes, but not sure it might cause the problem

Comment: Did the slowdown happen after you changed the code to use multi-thread or it used to run fast enough using multi-thread but you change something else in the code and make it slow?

Comment: No, Dikei. This codes has been used multi-thread and fast vs. now. I had removed some unused codes and convert CString to std::string.

Comment: If those two files arent at the same physical location on the harddrive, multithreaded access to them will cause increased seek activity of the HDD, thus slowing down things (even worse when the files are fragmented). Depending on how often you parse those files, it might be beneficial to make sure that they are in adjacent physical locations on the HDD.

Comment: Really, good to know. Is there a solution to void that?

Comment: @AndrewS: No easy solutions i know of... Users should regularly defragment their HDD.. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have shared resources amongst your threads, such as the vector mystr then you need to use thread synchronization mechanisms to access these resources, otherwise your vector will get corrupted.

This is true for any variable that will be accessed from multiple threads at once, if they are being written to by at least one thread.

I cannot say what the problem is as you are not providing enough data, I cannot make out from your code what variables are local, and which one's aren't and which variables are only used by one or by multiple threads.

Comment: vector mystr, it is not sharing resource. I just used same vector name with other function. Can it cause problem?

Comment: where is it declared, this vector, I don't see it in your function scope?